# Why is flushing not working on System.err?

Tags: java, stream, java-8, printstream

I'm developing a main class that writes potential exceptions by means of
`e.printStackTrace()` and which finishes with

```
System.err.flush();
System.out.println("\n>>> EXITING...");
```

The issue is that when exception trace is big, my exiting message is still printed in the middle of all the error sermon.

What I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Are multiple threads involved?

Comment: I'm fear it's not deterministic, since my private code uses different operations with different lags, and the buffer can be full or not, and every terminal has its performance. It's a bit of a hit and miss until I reach the situation, so I don't think a benchmarking is needed. It must be a conceptual problem. C'mon its single-threaded, and logically replicable with 3 lines.

Comment: At least somebody could tell if it's an expected issue or not, before furthering research

Comment: `err` and `out` are two separate streams.  Even if you flush the output, that just means all the characters have been sent to the o/s.  The terminal(?) reading both streams might still interleave the two streams when it displays them.

Comment: I was fearing that. Thanks! Could you write it in an answer form so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `System.err` and `System.out` are two separate streams. Even if you flush the output, that just means all the characters have been sent to the o/s. The terminal(?) reading both streams might still interleave the two streams when it displays them.

One remedy might be to tie the streams together, effectively directing the `System.err` stream to be written to `System.out`, but you will lose any colouring etc that distinguishes the two streams when displayed.

Comment: I used this solution with the addition of a small ninja trick to overcome the problem of loss of color. In the case of error messages I added the character \uD83D\uDD25 at the string to highlight the errors! :). Examle:                       System.out.println("\uD83D\uDD25\uD83D\uDD25\uD83D\uDD25 -> My error!!!");

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. I added Thread.sleep(5) after the flush. Then it worked.

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others